# How to install Cargo on a RHEL Linux server?

Tags: linux, rust, centos, rhel, rust-cargo

I tried installing Cargo on a RHEL server with:

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

but after finishing, I get the response:

```
cargo
-bash: cargo: command not found
```

Is there a different way to install?

Comment: Did you check that the script actually puts anything onto your `$PATH`? It might use `~/.local/bin` or some other non-standard location for binaries.

Comment: [This](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install) says it puts binaries into `~/.cargo/bin`. Is it on your `$PATH`?

Comment: Put `source ~/.cargo/env` to your `~/.bash_profile`. It prepends `~/.cargo/bin` to your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

1. First enable the `rhel-7-variant-devtools-rpms` repository

   `subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-varient-devtools-rpms`

   > Replace `variant` with the Red Hat Enterprise Linux system variant (`server` or `workstation`)
2. Enable the `rhel-variant-rhscl-7-rpms` repository:

   `subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-variant-rhscl-7-rpms`
3. Add the Red Hat Developer Tools key to your system:

   `cd /etc/pki/rpm-gpg`

   `wget -O RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-devel https://www.redhat.com/security/data/a5787476.txt`

   `rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-devel`

   Once the subscription is attached to the system and repositories enabled, you can install Red Hat Rust Toolset
4. Then install `rust-toolset-7`

   `yum install rust-toolset-7`

   Cargo is provided by the `rust-toolset-7-cargo` package and is automatically installed with the `rust-toolset-7` package.

Comment: `No package rust-toolset-7 available.`

Comment: Please enable the redhat developer tool by using subscription manager